# Error in knnImputation in r: Not sufficient complete cases for computing neighbors

Tags: r, data-imputation

I did the knn imputation following this post:
[KNN imputation R packages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61110/knn-imputation-r-packages)

I met the error: Not sufficient complete cases for computing neighbors. Even when k = 1, this error occurs.

```
data.imputed <- knnImputation(data, k=3)
Error in knnImputation(data) : 
Not sufficient complete cases for computing neighbors.
```

However the data should have sufficient complete cases. What's the problem?

```
dim(data)
[1]  779 1558
sum(complete.cases(data))
[1] 600
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this question would better belong on StackOverflow but I'll give it a go anyway:

paraphrasing the code for knnImputation (https://gist.github.com/tengpeng/fb6809717361319d8bde), you get that error message under the following conditions:

```
xcomplete <- data[setdiff(1:nrow(data),which(!complete.cases(data))),]
if (nrow(xcomplete) < k)
    stop("Not sufficient complete cases for computing neighbors.")
```

I suggest you check the value of nrow(xcomplete) is equal to 600.

EDIT: As described in [PR#16648](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16648), complete.cases can lead to spurious errors when some columns have classes with length or is.na methods, for example "POSIXlt".